# Change Background Color of appended tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey I add some rows to a table, after I check if the current DateTime is between start DateTime and the end DateTime of the current row, if this is true I want to change the background color of the row.

```
   $('#calendarTable').append(calendarRow);
   setCurrentLesson(field, calendarRow);

function setCurrentLesson(field, calendarRow){
  var currentDateTime = new Date();
  currentDateTime.setFullYear(field.tafel_datum.split("-")[0]);
  currentDateTime.setMonth(field.tafel_datum.split("-")[1]);
  currentDateTime.setMonth(currentDateTime.getMonth() -1); 
  currentDateTime.setDate(field.tafel_datum.split("-")[2]);

  //console.log(currentDateTime.setMonth(0)); -- Januar

  var startTime = field.tafel_von;
  var endTime = field.tafel_bis;

  var startDateTime =new Date(currentDateTime.getTime());
  startDateTime.setHours(startTime.split(":")[0]);
  startDateTime.setMinutes(startTime.split(":")[1]);
  startDateTime.setSeconds(startTime.split(":")[2]);

  endDateTime = new Date(currentDateTime.getTime());
  endDateTime.setHours(endTime.split(":")[0]);
  endDateTime.setMinutes(endTime.split(":")[1]);
  endDateTime.setSeconds(endTime.split(":")[2]);

  if(startDateTime < currentDateTime && endDateTime > currentDateTime){

** Change Background Color of the calendarRow**
     }
    }
```

Comment: you need to change the style of the row. If your rows don't have an id, assign them one, for it will make it a lot easier.

Comment: im new to jquery, how can I add the ID to a new appended row?

Comment: don't you create the table manually? if so, just add them manually too. Otherwise, the jQuery function `$(calendarRow).prop("id", "id for the row")`

Comment: Then, to give it color: `$("#whateverRowYouWant").prop("background-color", "yellow")`

Comment: Oh, but I see you're passing the row as a parameter, so you can just do `$(calendarRow).css("background-color", "yellow")` without giving it an id

Comment: i add the row via String, see my comment below.

Comment: ohhh it's a String... Then, wherever you create that string, give it an id too, so you can use it like `$("#whateverRowYouWant").css("background-color", "yellow")` with no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the style attribute inside `setCurrentLesson()` function, since you are passing it as one of the parameter.

```
var index = $('#calendarTable').find(`tr`).length-1;
$('#calendarTable').find(`tr`).eq(index).attr('style','background-color:green;');
```

or you can also add a class to it

```
var index = $('#calendarTable').find(`tr`).length-1;
$('#calendarTable').find('tr').eq(index).addClass('activeRow');
```

```js
var index = $('#calendarTable').find(`tr`).length-1; $('#calendarTable').find(`tr`).eq(index).attr('style','background-color:green;');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="calendarTable" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: then i need to select the last tr from table first, right?
because in var calendarRow is a String = 

`var calendarRow = '<tr><td>' + field.tafel_datum + '</td><td>' + weekDay + '</td><td>' + field.tafel_von + '</td><td>' + field.tafel_bis
        + '</td><td>' + field.tafel_lehrer + '</td><td>' + field.tafel_fach + '</td><td>' + field.tafel_raum + '</td></tr>';`

Comment: depends, is your `calendarRow` that you are adding is same as rest of the row?

Comment: `calendarRow` is the row you add to your calendar table, right ? So you can just add style to it : `$(calendarRow).css("background-color", "green")`

Comment: @soywood but calendarRow  may be identical to some other row. vaekek you are correct, you just need to add the style to last row since you are appending new row. either by `:last-child` or by `.eq()`

Comment: @ab29007 but how can i select the last row? since I don't have an ID.
`calendarRow = $('#calendarRow tr:last').attr("id");` will not work, right?